# how can I manage session with mod_wsgi with apache webserver?

Tags: python, apache, session, authentication, mod-wsgi

I've created a python script running under mod_wsgi with apache,
I want to manage sessions, authentication and timeout.

what would be the best way to achieve it?

I'm using apache 2.x and mod_wsgi 2.x

I've seen few mod_wsgi Directives but any help or article_URL may help me more.

References:
[mod_wsgi Directive Reference for Authentication](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/AccessControlMechanisms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Middleware and libraries for WSGI"](http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/libraries.html)

Comment: Link says "Page does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

See the WSGI middleware package called AuthKit.

http://authkit.org/

Comment: This link seems owned by somebody else now.  New link is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AuthKit

Answer (score -2):

Don't try and re-invent the wheel. Use a framework.